# Getting odd/even part of a sequence with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a list of all `Projects`, and that I group them by `Category` like this:

```
var projectsByCat = from p in Projects
                    group p by p.Category into g
                    orderby g.Count() descending
                    select new { Category = g.Key, Projects = g };
```

Now I want to display this as a list in a web page, where first I create the left side div, secondly the right side div. I am ordering by number of `Projects` in each `Category` to show the `Categories` with the most `Projects` on top - thus I would like to split `projectsByCat` in two - if I put all the "odd numbered" `Categories` on the left and the "even numbered" categories on the right, I think I will get a reasonably sane view.

So I thought I could do this to get the odd and even members of `projectsByCat`:

```
var oddCategories = projectsByCat.Where((cat, index) => index % 2 != 0);

var evenCategories = projectsByCat.Where((cat, index) => index % 2 == 0);
```

And it compiles - however, when I run it, I get an exception such as this:

> Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Where'.

And I thought I was safe since it compiled in the first place.. ;)

Is there an elegant way to do this? And also, is there an elegant explanation for why my creative use of `Where()` won't work?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you're using LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities you should first fully materialize the results into memory:

```
var oddCategories  = projectsByCat.ToList().Where((c,i) => i % 2 != 0);
var evenCategories = projectsByCat.ToList().Where((c,i) => i % 2 == 0);
```

It isn't possible to iterate through results on the database with an indexer without the use of a cursor, which either ORM framework does **not** do.

Comment: That did it - I do 95% LINQ to objects so the possibility of this being a problem with LINQ to SQL didn't even hit me. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

Note that calling `.ToList()` twice for the same query is going query the database twice.

It would be much better to cache the result in an intermediate list, *then* apply your predicate filtering:

```
var projectsByCat =
    (from p in Projects
    group p by p.Category into g
    orderby g.Count() descending
    select new { Category = g.Key, Projects = g }).ToList();

var oddCategories = projectsByCat.Where((cat, index) => index % 2 != 0);
var evenCategories = projectsByCat.Where((cat, index) => index % 2 == 0);
```

Answer (score 5):

The oddCategories and the evenCategories are backward.

Indexes start a 0 not 1

0 % 2 = 0

0 index is odd.

```
var oddCategories  = projectsByCat.Where((cat, index) => index % 2 == 0);

var evenCategories = projectsByCat.Where((cat, index) => index % 2 != 0);
```

Comment: index % 2 == 0 is gives even, not odd.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do this using LINQ, and avoiding multiple enumerations over the input, is to do a grouping or similar on whether each item is even or odd.

A simple way using the overload for `Select` that [mixes in an index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) coupled with [`ToLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211(v=vs.100).aspx) gives you what you want:

```
var oddsAndEvens = input
    .ToList() // if necessary to get from IQueryable to IEnumerable
    .Select((item, index) => new { isEven = index % 2 == 0, item })
    .ToLookup(
        i => i.isEven,
        i => i.item);
```

This will produce a [`Lookup<TKey, TElement>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.100).aspx) data structure that has the [following benefit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292716(v=vs.100).aspx):

> If the key is not found in the collection, an empty sequence is returned.

This means that after the above LINQ query you can do:

```
var evens = oddsAndEvens[true];
var odds = oddsAndEvens[false];
```

Comment: isEven = index % 2 != 0 is not even, it's odd actually.

Answer (score 2):

You can separate odd and even in your view using linq.

```
//even 
@foreach (var item in Model.Where((item, index) => index % 2 == 0))
{
     //do the code
}

//odd
@foreach (var item in Model.Where((item, index) => index % 2 != 0))
{
     //do the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "this is a test <string> to extract odd <index> values after split";
var parts = text.Split(new char[] { '<', '>' });
IEnumerable words = parts.Where(x => parts.ToList().IndexOf(x) % 2 == 1)
```

*words* would contain "string" and "index"

Answer (score 0):

You Can find Even odd number without foreach loop

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> lstnum = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    List<int> lstresult = lstnum.FindAll(x => (x % 2) == 0);

    lstresult.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq GroupBy Method:

```
    List<string> lista = new List<string> { "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro" };

    var grupoXindices = lista.GroupBy(i => (lista.IndexOf(i) % 2) == 0);
    foreach (var grupo in grupoXindices) 
    {
    Console.WriteLine(grupo.Key);                
    foreach (var i in grupo) Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```