# Template Razor Delegates - alternate row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I extend this List template razor delegate example that Phil Haack mentions here, so that I can provide an alternate row css class?

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx

I would like to do something similar to this:

```
@comics.List(
  @< tr class="@odd">
    < td>@item.Title< /td>
    < td>@item.Publisher< /td>
  )
```

**Edit:** I don't need a javascript or css solution.  I need to be able to support older browsers and browsers that may have javascript disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must have a server side solution, something like this will do it:

```
@{ var odd = false; }

@comics.List(
    @<tr class="@((odd = !odd) ? "odd-row" : "")">
        <td>@item.Title</td>
        <td>@item.Publisher</td>
  )
```

It should result in:

```
<tr class="odd-row">
<tr class="">
<tr class="odd-row">
```

The `(odd = !odd)` is a boolean test plus a **NOT** operation that toggles the flag.

Comment: I would recommend changing the sentinel value to an integer initialized to 1 and the test to odd++ % 2 == 1

Comment: @Tommy because I didn't read Paul's answer closely enough.  +1 for elegance.

Answer (score 2):

I assume using just CSS would also solve your stated problem:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Update of my answer after your **Edit**

I was not familiar with this `Razor` templating mechanism, thanks for sharing, anyway I read up on it to understand it better.

Unfortunately it does not seem possible.  As the underlying `HelperResult` expects a single parameter named `@item` and more parameters cannot be added.  [This article](http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2010/8/2/inside-razor-part-3-templates.html) explains the issue clearly.

I guess it is possible write a specific table template using thistechnique and achieve your desired result but IMHO the `foreach` route is simpler.

Comment: +1 CSS is the easiest way to achieve the requirement. Would something like this be any good to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267033/getting-odd-even-part-of-a-sequence-with-linq

Comment: Thanks for the link Nick.  That won't help me build up a list or alternating rows.  I know how to achieve alternate rows using a simple foreach loop, I'm looking to create something with very easy to use syntax, like the Template Razor Delegates example I posted.